# Combining multiple Models in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, ruby-on-rails-2

```
class BankTeller < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :finance_transaction
  belongs_to :institution_bank_account
end

class InstitutionBankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bank_tellers
end

class FinanceTransaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bank_teller
end
```

Finance transaction has an `amount` field. How do I fetch the sum of amount in all Finance Transactions grouping them by InstitutionBankAccount?

EDIT: my application is in Rails Version 2.3.8.

Comment: BankTeller.all.joins(:finance_transaction, :institution_bank_account).select("institution_bank_accounts.id,sum(finance_transactions.amount)").group("institution_bank_accounts.id")

Comment: @irene That didn't work. I got an error "undefined method `joins' for #<Array:0x14903160>". I use rails 2.3.8.

Comment: Replace BankTeller.all through BankTeller, all is to much.

Comment: Still didn't work. I get error, "private method `select' called for #<Class:0x14ea5b18>"

Comment: Does BankTeller.joins(:finance_transaction, :institution_bank_account) works?

Comment: No. I get error, "undefined method `joins'". I think its because my application uses an old Rails version (Rails 2.3.8)

Comment: Then try with BankTeller.all(:joins => [:finance_transaction, :institution_bank_account]) and look here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
BankTeller.all(:joins => [:finance_transaction, :institution_bank_account], :group => "institution_bank_accounts.id", :select=> ('institution_bank_accounts.id, sum(amount)'))
```